# Laravel 5.2 auth functionality doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I used laravel 5.1 for the previous project and I had no problem with it, but now I installed Laravel 5.2 and I got a problem with auth functionality
so I use the following routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
  Route::controllers([
    "auth" => "Auth\AuthController",
    "password" => "Auth\PasswordController"
  ]) ;
});
```

And it's ok I can see my auth form but when I send the form to the post route `/auth/login` the session isn't set so I got the redirect but when I check if I logged in or not `Auth::check()` I get `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only the Authentication routes need to use the `web` middleware group; all routes which require the functionality it provides need to use it too.

For example

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::auth();
});

Route::get('example-1', function () {
    dd(Auth::check()); // always will return false
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('example-2', function () {
        dd(Auth::check()); // works
    });
});
```

The web middleware group simply collects and runs lots of middleware for you.

```
'web' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
],
```

You'll notice `StartSession::class` above. This means that for every request which you expect session data be available (for Auth and such) you'll need to have run this Middleware.

Either by using the `web` group, or explicitly calling that middleware on the route/route groups you want.

Answer (score 2):

use this  `Route::auth();` simply

Comment: if you mean this 

`Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
  Route::auth();
});` 

then I got `NotFoundHttpException`

Comment: Yeah, ok, I changed url and now it works, but I still got `false` when I check `Auth::check()`

Comment: Are you using `Auth::check()` in a controller or route using the web middleware?

Comment: Yes, in the controller

Comment: @HamelRaj Okay, here's my controler
http://www.imghost.in/img/2016-03/21/z7ncrxi04p9vgp4o8pfna6g2q.png
http://www.imghost.in/img/2016-03/21/7r9fh5skmgtla9kwezpsenqts.png

Comment: And the the route definition of that controller is within a group using the `web` middleware? Auth routes, AND controller routes which want access to auth need to be use `web`.

Comment: No worries. Have posted as an answer.